# How to locate a hidden element on a webpage

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to pass some content in the textbox using the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').send_keys(value)
```

Apparently nothing is getting passes.
Similar issue with clicking button:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').click()
```

This is also not working, in the code i could see

> display:none:

```
<li style="display:none">
</li>
</ul></div>                        
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
<label for="Username">Username</label>
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val- 
required="User name is Required" id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: what Xpath you have tried mention that !

Comment: this is the xpath: //*[@id="Username"]

Comment: Error trace please.

Comment: if you can provide the website url, or a bit of HTML , that'd be helpful!

Comment: The `display: none` code is part of `li` tag which does not affect the username field. It is possible that the element found is wrong/different.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared and @Sighil pointed out the **style** attribute **display: none** is part of the previous `<li>` tag which must not affect the **Username** field. To pass some text to the **Username** field you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='Username']").send_keys("Dimple Mathew")
```

It may be possible you have to induce a waiter for the *Username* field to be interactable and in that case you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='Username']"))).send_keys("Dimple Mathew")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait statement before you use sendkeys or click. As per my understanding element is not visible while click or sendkeys.

[For your reference visit Explicit and Implicit Wait Docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue not to long ago, try this:

```
js= "document.getElementById('Username').value = '" + str(YOURVALUE) + "';"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

It worked for me, hope this helps.